# How do I access local directory using TestComplete

Tags: automated-testing, testcomplete

I need to verify a file has been created locally and need to delete this file as well, how do I do it using JavaScript in TestComplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using: aqFileSystem object? With it, you can

- Find a file / directory
- Modify a file / directory
- Delete a file / directory
- Create a file / directory

Please refer to this link for more information [aqFileSystem doc](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/program-objects/aqfilesystem/index.html)